# Simple negative index listing while loop. Don't understand why it's not working correctly :/

Tags: python, list, indexing, while-loop

I'm working on a simple negative index listing while loop for class and I don't understand why it's not working correctly.

Instead of printing:

4

3

2

1

I'm getting:

1

4

3

2

Any help pointing out what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Professor's exercise:

```
def loop_using_negative_indexes(my_list):
    """
    03. Access all the items in a list with negative indexes
    Finish this function below which takes a list as parameter and prints the items in a reversed order.
    You should do this with negative indexes,
    e.g. my_list[-1] is the last item and my_list[-2] is the 2nd last.
    You can choose to use either for loop or while loop to do this.
    There is no explicit return value of this function.
    """
```

My coding:

```
    i = 0
    while i < len(my_list):
        print(my_list[-i])
        i += 1
```

Professor's test:

```
#test for Q3
new_list = [1,2,3,4]
loop_using_negative_indexes(new_list)
```

Comment: Hint: `-0 == 0`

Comment: "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors." —  Phil Karlton & Leon Bambrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a couple of off-by-one errors.

And as I said in the comment, `-0 == 0`, so `a[-0]` is the same as `a[0]`, i.e., it accesses the first item in `a`.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

i = 1
while i <= len(my_list):
    print(my_list[-i])
    i += 1
```

**output**

```
4
3
2
1
```

---

As Davis Herring mentions, it's more Pythonic to iterate directly over the items in a sequence rather than doing it indirectly via indexing. OTOH, it's important to do exercises like this that practice using indices to develop your understanding of how indices work.

Comment: Completely makes sense, but indexing making i = 1 will only index 3 numbers in the list giving me "4,3,2"

Comment: Not sure if it's correct, but it worked putting "print(my_list[0])" as the last statement in the while loop.

Comment: @MCraft: Note that the while loop condition should be `<=` not `<` which would explain why you get `4, 3, 2`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! There go those critical reading skills and obvious answers.

Answer (score 0):

-0 is still 0.  As such, [backward indexing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) is 1-based (or -1-based, perhaps).  You can write directly

```
for i in range(-1,-len(my_list)-1,-1):
```

or indirectly (with fewer -1s)

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
  print(my_list[-i-1])
```

or, much more Pythonically when it's not homework,

```
for x in reversed(my_list):
```

Comment: Apparently, using a for loop and ranging it would have been a much better option. TY

Comment: @MCraft: The 1-basing actually makes that `range` call horrible; I wrote it out to show the difference.  I'll edit it to show an alternative that might be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` loop with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i, _ in enumerate(my_list, 1):
    print(my_list[-i])
```

`enumerate()` is used to generate the index starting from 1. We don't need the values from the list that `enumerate()` returns, so they are bound to `_` to indicate that we don't care. Using `enumerate()` is a little cleaner than using `for i in range(1, len(my_list)+1):`, although it will execute a little slower.

With a `while` loop you can start your counter from 1 instead of 0:

```
i = 1
while i <= len(my_list):
    print(my_list[-i])
    i += 1
```